# Is there a way to generate Typescript interfaces and classes from the official OpenAPI schema document?

Tags: typescript, openapi, jsonschema

I need to generate Typescript interfaces or classes for the objects defined in the official OpenAPI JSON Schema found [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/schemas/v3.1/schema.json).  In other words, I need interfaces/classes for things like a Components object and a Schema object.

I have tried the tool located at [transform.tools](https://transform.tools/json-schema-to-typescript), but it doesn't seem to like the $ref statements and I can't seem to get any of the dereferencing tools to dereference that schema.

My overall goal here is to avoid hand coding the objects that are defined in the OAS JSON schema.

Is this possible?

Here is an example of the code that I'd like to create:

```
import openapiTS, { OpenAPI3, SchemaObject } from 'openapi-typescript';


declare module 'openapi-typescript' {
export interface OpenAPI3 {
    findSchema: (path: string) => SchemaObject | undefined;
    }
}

OpenAPI3.prototype.findSchema = function (path: string): 
SchemaObject | undefined {
    const instance = OpenAPI3(this);
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: So, runtime classes or dev-time interfaces? That's different things

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-typescript

Comment: @Dimava, I need dev-time interfaces.  openapi-typescript is very close to what I need, but not quite.  I may have to fork that repo and adapt it for my needs.  My idea was to create an extension function on the `SchemaObject` interface prototype to add a `findProperty()` function that searches the object's properties for a given path.  But the `SchemaObject` interface is not exported in such a way as to allow me to do that (at least as far as I can see).

Comment: Please provide the actual usage example code you want to make working

Comment: I edited the original question to show the code that I'm trying to create.  But I can't reference `OpenAPI3` because it isn't exported (I assume) in the way that I need for it to me.  Since I couldn't make this work, my thought was to instead generate from the OpenAPI JSON schema the types/interfaces/classes that I need.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I ended up solving this was to use the [openapi3-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi3-ts) package.  It exports interfaces that match the types specified in OpenAPI3.0 and OpenAPI3.1 specifications.

I was able to load the API schema document and pass objects to my validation routine, and then code validation functions for each property type.  It's about 99% of what I originally intended to do, I just could not extend a prototype since everything is an interface instead of a class.  But this solution allows me to utilize a third-party library to maintain compatibility with the latest OpenAPI specifications.

Here are the signatures of the functions that I implemented:

```
import type { SchemaObject as Oas31SchemaObject } from 'openapi3-ts/oas31';
import type { SchemaObject as Oas30SchemaObject } from 'openapi3-ts/oas30';

export type SchemaObject = Oas30SchemaObject | Oas31SchemaObject;

export function validate(schema: SchemaObject, path: string, values:  Array<string | number | boolean>, op?: string): ValidationResult{}

function isValidValue(obj: SchemaObject, value: any, op?: string): ValidationResult {}

function isValidString(value: string, obj: SchemaObject, op?: string): ValidationResult {}

function isValidNumber(value: number, obj: SchemaObject): ValidationResult {}

function isValidInteger(value: number, obj: SchemaObject): ValidationResult {}

function isValidBoolean(value: boolean): ValidationResult {}
```

Answer (score 0):

try autorest from Azure. They have a really nice SDK generator

https://github.com/Azure/autorest.typescript/tree/main/packages/autorest.typescript

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy! That project looks interesting. I'll definitely take a look.